# sfml - put all objects in array

Tags: c++, arrays, sfml

i'm working on a game and want that when i create an object it gets added to an array (so it's easier to draw and maybe
change coords and stuff).
I only don't know how to do it.
If it helps here is my function:

```
void CreateTile(string Texture, sf::Vector2f Pos)
{
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile(Texture);
    sf::Sprite Tile;
    Tile.setTexture(texture);
    Tile.setPosition(Pos);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search for `std::vector`.

Comment: Why are you making a game when you haven't mastered the basics of C++?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Comment: just be sure not to store sf::Texture object directly in a vector as it is not a lightweight object :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a container from the standard library, the most basic one is the [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). `sf::Texture`objects are heavy objects that should not be needlessly copied around. You should keep them in one place and only *reference* them when needed.

```
std::vector<sf::Sprite*> sprites;
std::vector<sf::Texture*> textures;

void CreateTile(const std::string& file, const sf::Vector2f& position)
{
    sf::Texture* texture = new sf::Texture();
    texture->loadFromFile(file);

    textures->push_back(texture);

    sf::Sprite* tile = new sf::Sprite();
    tile->setTexture(*texture);
    tile->setPosition(position);

    sprites->push_back(tile);
}
```

And as this aims to be modern C++, you should **not** use raw pointers like above. Use *smart* pointers like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

**Warning:** The solution will not be to just copy this code and hope it somehow works. Get a good book on the basics of C++ and read it cover to cover. There is no shortcuts. You need to learn the language if you want to code a game.